# Instabug map is not available in screenshot

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, mapfragment, instabug

This is the code where I add the map to instabug:

```
    Log.i("","entered here... map:" + mMap + "...." + mMapFragment.getView());
                                PSLocationCenter.getInstance().instabug.addMapView(mMapFragment.getView(), mMap);
```

Where I get this log:

```
04-01 14:28:55.455: I/(26117): entered here... map:com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap@5091193....android.widget.FrameLayout{7dbac34 V.E...C.. .......D 0,0-1080,1776}
```

As you can see. my map exists, and also the fragment. The initMap function is in the BaseActivity, and other classes to have the map inside instabug.
This is my map:
[image]

And this is what I see in instabug:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Instabug we hold `WeakReference<GoogleMap>` so can you try switching the GoogleMap variable to a global variable in your class and tell me how it goes?

I've also noticed you're using v1+ of Instabug, I'd recommend using v2 as it contains a lot of bug fixes and enhancements aside from the UI rehall and the new features :)

And please don't hesitate to contact us on our support channels through the website anytime.

Comment: the GoogleMap variable is global on the BaseActivity. Changed to v2 for now and will let you know how it works

Comment: is there an sample on how to initialize instabug on the website?
This doesn't work for me anymore Instabug.initialize(this) and then the setters on it (comment required, presendingrunnable, etc)

Comment: And from where can I get my app token? I haven't had one for v1. your website doesn't say anything about a app token

Comment: You can find a sample app [here](https://github.com/Instabug/android-sample). And regarding the `app_token`, you can find it on the website when you navigate to your application then open up the SDK tab @rosualin

Comment: Are this 3 not supported anymore?
setPostFeedbackMessage, setPostBugReportMessage, setCommentFieldHint

Comment: Updated to v2 and this still happens. And the googleMap variable is a global one already :(

Comment: I had the same problem using com.instabug.library:instabug:2+ but solved it by registering the map manually using Instabug's API Instabug.addMapView(mapFragment.getView(), mMap);   After this invoking Instabug manually or by shaking could create a screenshot. Tested on S7 running Android 6.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been solved since version 3.0.0.
You just need to upgrade to latest version >= v3.0.5